# NetBeans - is there any way to disable the recurring error badges?

Tags: netbeans, badge, netbeans-8

In NetBeans 8.0.1 error badges are recursive back to the project name from a file that has errors in it. This makes most of my projects look like they have errors that need to be fixed, even if the errors are being generated from code in, for example, WordPress. Not wanting to mess with WordPress core code I'm stuck with the error. Some working template files that contain code fragments also throw errors that I'm aware of and OK with.

It looks like this.

[image: Error badge example]

I've looked around the web and I can't find a way of removing these badges, just a load of related bug reports to NetBeans. Is there a way of removing these error badges? (I'm OK with them being on files with "errors", but I don't want them recursive back to the project name.)

I'm aware that I can set the mime type of php files to text/plain in `Tools -> Options -> Misc -> Files`, but that also disables syntax highlighting. That's not the answer for me.

I've come across posts on the web that mention the `-J-Dnb.php.silent.error.badge=true` option, but I've not been able to get this to work. Either it doesn't work, or I'm doing something wrong.

Can you help?

Comment: Well, all I can say is that I used Netbeans for the past 3 years and it always had "recursive badges" whenever an error, warning or git changed status afffected just one of files of project: always went back to the project. anyway, an error on project is not an impediment of running it, it'll eventually make java crash with an exception. Why not create a separate project with Wordpress Code Core separate and then associate the project with the WP project on build & run? using this method you'll be able to distinguish WP errors from other ones.

Comment: Also when you use that option, the file, which causes errors has to be reindexed. So open it and modify, or let the whole project to be reindexed (e.g. clean NB userdir). If the error is from an html you should use -J-Dnb.html.silent.error.badge=true